# Continuous position scales with no effect on the spacing between the bar and the x axis in ggplot2 with R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart, space

I am designing a bar  plot with `ggplot2` package.
The only problem is that I cannot get rid of the space between the bars and the x-axis.
I know that this formula should resolve the problem:

```
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) function
```

But it seems that the element for the error bar is overwriting it and gives always this space.

here my code:

```
p<-ggplot(data=tableaumergectrlmut, aes(x=ID, y=meanNSAFbait,  fill=Condition)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+ 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=meanNSAFbait-SDNSAFbait, 
  ymax=meanNSAFbait+SDNSAFbait, width=0.25), position=position_dodge(.9))
```

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example? Probably you can demonstrate this on a built-in data set, but if not you should share your data with `dput()` or via simulation. [See here for tips on making reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: Also, it's nice if examples are *minimal* - helps remove things that distract from the actual problem. If the custom colors, labels, angled text, theme customizations, etc., aren't part of the problem, remove them from your question.

Comment: By using expand = c(0,0) you set the limits of your y axis to the maximum and minimum y value in your dataset. If your errorbars are perhaps so large that they go below zero (weird but possible), the minimum will thus be this value (e.g. -1), and not zero. Perhaps try and add ,limits=c(0,0) to scale_y_continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some example data to generate a plot that (I think) shows the problem you're having.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(val = c(10, 20, 100, 5), name = LETTERS[1:4])

ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = val, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

There is a gap from the zero point on the y axis (bottom of the bars) and where the x axis labels are.

You can remove this using `scale_y_discrete` or `scale_y_continuous`, depending on the nature of your data, and setting `expand` to `c(0,0)`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = val, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))
```

This gives the plot:

[image]

Note I've also removed the gap along the y axis, simply remove the `scale_x_discrete` line to add this gap back in.

Since error bars are an issue, here are a few examples:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = val, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = val - 10,
                    ymax = val + 10))
```

[image]

You can use scale to remove the padding down to the error bar:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = val, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = val - 10,
                    ymax = val + 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Or you can use coord_cartesian to give a hard cutoff:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = val, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = val - 10,
                    ymax = val + 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(df$val) + 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you for the plot you show as an example. I can obtain this result as well, but as soon as I add the error bar, the spacing appears again.

Comment: I've added some with error bars. Does this highlight (and solve) the issue you're having?

Comment: Yes, this highlights completely my issue. I tried to add again      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) at the end as you did and it finally works as expected! Thank you very much.